Using another's python code as a folder inside my folder and using files from both
I have the following code structure in python:


Application
├── app
│   ├── data/
│   ├── utils/
│   │   └── utils.py
│   └── main.py
├── utils2/
│   └── utils2.py
└── main2.py



I downloaded the code in the folder app/ from github, so when we run the file main.py, the data is imported in the utils.py file as  :
from data import *

Now when I need to run main2.py, I need to access the functions in utils.py, and also the files in folder data, so for that I need to import the data in utils.py as
from app.data import *

This is creating a problem when running main.py and main2.py
What is the correct way of importing and using the folders and files so that only one import statement works for both scenarios?
I am using python 3.9

The answer is to use absolute imports in the utils.py file as:
from app.data import *

Then to run main2.py, we need to use:
python main2.py

while being inside the app folder.
and to run main.py, we need to use:
python -m app.main

this way we can run both files without conflicts.
